# How to replace some words,numbers,characters

Tags: php, replace

In my database many posts has some characters like :

[media id=468 width=660 height=440]

With php i want to get media id (the number) and replace it with another function, also after taking the id, dont want that  [media id=468 width=660 height=440]  to be shown at my posts in html.

Please can some one help with this ?
Thank you a lot

PS : I dont need height and width.

Comment: Do you need the width and height as well?

Comment: no , i just need the media id , and dont want that that shortcode, to display in html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php):

```
function do_stuff($values) {
    return '<object id="' . $values['id'] . '" />';
}

$text = 'some stuff [media id=468 width=660 height=440] more stuff';

$new_text = preg_replace_callback('@\[media id=(?P<id>\S+) width=\S+ height=\S+\]@', 
                      'do_stuff', $text);

echo "text: $text\n new text: $new_text";
```

Will give you

```
text: some stuff [media id=468 width=660 height=440] more stuff
new text: some stuff <object id="468" /> more stuff
```

---

If you change your `do_stuff()` callback:

```
function do_stuff($values) {
    $allowed = array('468', '222'); 

    if (in_array($values['id'], $allowed)) {
        return '<object id="' . $values['id'] . '" />';
    } else {
        return $values[0]; 
    }
}
```

This will just give you back the same text if id is not 468 or 222. This is a fairly simple example, I am sure you can figure out how to tweak the behavior to suit your needs.

Comment: can this be done :  if that shortcode exist on post do the stuff you pasted , if no dont do nothing. Thank you